# Clear up all the divs in a modal when cancel is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I have this modal. How to reset all the divs in the modal?

DetailSection has some elements in it which show up.
The modal shows up like in screenshot1. Then I do a search by and the data appears like so highlighted in screenshot2.
Then I click on cancel. After trying to open the modal again, the highlighted in screenshot2 shows up. I expect everything to clear and start fresh. But it is not clearing up things.

Comment: the code you provided has syntax errors and appears to be missing context, but you can set a `key` prop on the SendToFaxUploadModal based on whatever criteria should make different content show in the modal, which will reset any state local to the component. However, it doesn't appear you are using local state within that component. The definitions for the functions used within `clearAll` are missing, so it's unclear what the actual issue is without more context.

Comment: @shamsup: I didn't think anyone would care to read it because its so lengthy. But, I edited the question and added the functions used within clearAA. I also added to viewEditDetails in the returnto render the UI again, thereby calling those handlers in the DetailSection. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @shamsup: YOu are correct. There is no local state for this Modal. Can you point me in the right direction as to why this component would need a local state and if so how to add localstate. Is it using mapstate to props? This is a modal dialog which performs an action. It does not really update anything in the UI. But it gets called from a couple of places because the action can be performed from a few places.

Comment: @shamsup: I guess then I don't know how  to actually update the state without re-render.  React does not like it if I call clearAll() inside the handlecloseAction .   const handleCloseAction = (event) => {
        clearAll();
        props.updateState({
            ...this.state,
            showfaxNow: false,
            
        });
        }